# Group_concat with joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, group-concatenation

I have the following scheme

```
users:        researches:                  researchyear:

uid | name    rid| titleAr                  rid     |  uid     | 
---+--------  ---+------------              --------+----------+
 1 | Peter     1 | Tennis                         1 |        1 |
 2 | Alice     2 | Football                       1 |        2 | 
 3 | Bob       3 | Basketball                     2 |        3 | 
                                                  3 |        1 |
                                                  3 |        3 | 
                                                  3 |        2 |
```

I would like to get a research with its researchers (users) by specific researcher_Id(uid),
i.e when I set user id (1,3 or 2) I would like to get the same result.

```
id |titleAr    | users_ids | users_names
---+-------+-----------+----------------------------
 3 |Basketball | 1,3,2     | Peter,Bob,Alice
```

I've tried the following query where I can get every research with its researchers (users):

```
SELECT r.rId,
       r.titleAr,
       Group_concat(u.userId ) users_ids ,
      Group_concat(u.name )      users_names
FROM   research r
           LEFT JOIN researchyear ry
                     ON r.rId = ry.rId
           LEFT  JOIN users u
                      ON ry.uId = u.userId
GROUP  BY r.rId, r.titleAr
```

How can I get it for one user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list all `users` names including the `uid` you want put this in your where clause:

```
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM researchyear t WHERE t.rid = r.id AND t.uid = {your_uid} )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to apply a row group filter, i.e. use a `HAVING` clause.  If you want to allow only the groups that contain a specific user/researcher, you can do that with the help of conditional count:

```
SELECT r.rId,
       r.titleAr,
       Group_concat(u.userId ) users_ids ,
       Group_concat(u.name )      users_names
FROM   research r
           LEFT JOIN researchyear ry
                     ON r.rId = ry.rId
           LEFT  JOIN users u
                      ON ry.uId = u.userId
GROUP  BY r.rId, r.titleAr
HAVING COUNT(CASE u.userId /* or: r.uid */ WHEN @specific_user_id THEN 1 END) > 0 ;
```

Note that conditional count can have various implementations in MySQL.  One of the shortest (if not the shortest one) is using `SUM`, so in your case it would be

```
...
HAVING SUM(u.userId = @specific_user_id) > 0 ;
/* or: SUM(r.uid = @specific_user_id) > 0 */
```

Unlike the `EXISTS` method suggested previously, this avoids hitting underlying tables more than once, which might result in better performance, although on small datasets the improvement, if any, would likely be negligible.